# Connection closed before full header was received pub get failed

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this kind of error message when I try to run the command `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`.

```
    Connection closed before full header was received pub get failed
    command: "C:\src\flutter_windows_3.7.10-stable\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --color       
    --directory ..\..\..\..\..\src\flutter_windows_3.7.10-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools get --example"        
    pub env: {
      "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter_windows_3.7.10-stable\flutter",
      "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
      "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
    }

exit code: 69
```

error Images (Screenshots)

[image]

I tried to fix it by deleting cash from flutter-SDK and running flutter pub get on Terminals but it didn't work then I delete both dart and flutter SDK and download them again and put their paths in the system environment and typed flutter doctor and this error still appear.

```
Here is how the error looks like
```

[image]

Comment: if you are in sanctioned countries like Iran or ... check your VPN connection

Comment: Run `pub get --verbose` and see if there is more info. If it is out-of-memory then it could be related to dependencies relying on different versions https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/16910

Comment: There is no API Call in my code